# FullCalendar debugging

Tags: debugging, fullcalendar

I couldn't find how to debug my fullcalendar code. I researched on FullCalendar documentation, I couldn't find anything about debugging. So, I need help to find an error.

My FullCalendar code is working one page but another page isn't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek' // günlük gösterim için bunu ekle -> ,agendaDay
        },
        defaultDate: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>',
        businessHours: true, // display business hours
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        eventLimit: true,

        events: [

        ...some code...

        ],
        eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
            eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl + "' width='30px' height='30px'/> ");
        }
    });

});
```

I'll give you all result data about unseen calendar page. if I have some events about 20 rows, I see calendar but below result I can't see the calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek' // günlük gösterim için bunu ekle -> ,agendaDay
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-09-28',
        businessHours: true, // display business hours
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        eventLimit: true,

        events: [

                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Kesin teminat mektubu geri teslimi', start: '2021-12-23', url: 'approve.php?reminder_ID=8&type=1', backgroundColor: '#A61E1E'},
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Kesin teminat mektubu geri teslimi', start: '2021-12-12', url: 'approve.php?reminder_ID=9&type=1', backgroundColor: '#A61E1E'},
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Kesin teminat mektubu geri teslimi', start: '2021-11-12', url: 'approve.php?reminder_ID=10&type=1', backgroundColor: '#A61E1E'},
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/03.png', title: 'Aylık Araç Raporu', start: '2016-10-15', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=1&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Aylık Denetim', start: '2016-09-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=2&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Aylık Maliyet Tablosu Onayının Alınması', start: '2016-10-05', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=3&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/03.png', title: 'Bütçe Sunumunun Hazırlanması', start: '2016-09-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=4&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Eğitim', start: '2016-10-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=5&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'İSG Yönetimi yıllık Çalışma Planı ve Yıllık Eğitim Planının Yapılması', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=7&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Personel Turnover Tutanağı', start: '2016-12-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=8&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Kışlık Kıyafet Verilmesi', start: '2017-09-09', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=9&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/03.png', title: 'Santral Birimi Gizli Müşteri Araması Yapılması', start: '2017-07-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=10&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Temizlik Firması 6 Aylık Değerlendirme Toplantısı', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=12&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Yazlık Kıyafet Verilmesi', start: '2017-03-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=13&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Yeni Dönem Temizlik Şartnamesi Hazırlanması', start: '2017-08-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=14&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/03.png', title: 'Yıllık Fiyat Karşılaştırması Yapılması', start: '2016-12-15', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=15&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: '6 Aylık tedarikçi değerlendirme', start: '2016-10-25', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=39&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Analiz Raporları', start: '2016-10-20', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=40&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Denetim', start: '2016-09-29', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=43&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'ISO 9000:2008 - ISO 22000 Sertifikası', start: '2017-07-11', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=44&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Kameralı Sayım Sistemi Raporu', start: '2016-10-15', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=46&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Kışlık Kıyafet Temini', start: '2016-10-20', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=47&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Masa üstü ve servis ekipmanları değişimi', start: '2016-12-20', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=48&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Portör Muayeneleri', start: '2017-03-03', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=51&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Sanitasyon', start: '2016-12-25', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=53&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Servis Tepsilerinin Değişimi', start: '2016-12-20', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=54&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Sigorta Poliçesi Yenilenme', start: '2016-12-15', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=56&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Şartnamenin hazırlanması', start: '2018-05-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=59&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Sigorta Poliçesi Yenilenme', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=60&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Yazlık Kıyafet Temini', start: '2017-05-19', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=63&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2016-12-20', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=64&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2016-12-20', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=65&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2016-12-25', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=66&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2016-12-25', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=67&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/02.png', title: 'Yıllık izin cetveli', start: '2016-12-20', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=70&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/05.png', title: 'Araç Organizasyon Birimi Aylık Faaliyet Raporu', start: '2016-10-05', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=71&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/05.png', title: 'Araç Takip Sistemi Raporu', start: '2016-10-05', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=72&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/05.png', title: 'Aylık Araç Sayımı Raporu', start: '2016-10-10', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=73&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/05.png', title: 'Aylık Şöför Ehliyet Kontrolü Raporu', start: '2016-10-05', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=74&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'yıkama alanı denetim formu oluşturulması raporun her ayın 10. gününe kadar yayınlanması', start: '2016-10-10', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=76&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'askı planları kontrolü', start: '2016-10-10', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=78&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'kira artış tutanağı hazırlanması', start: '2016-10-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=79&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'tesis emlak vergisi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=80&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2017-04-08', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=82&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'tesis emlak vergisi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=83&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'çevre temizlik vergisi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=85&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'ilan reklam vergisi beyanların verilmesi ve vergi ödemesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=87&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2016-10-13', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=89&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2017-01-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=90&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'kanuni merkez kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2017-02-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=91&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2016-10-23', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=93&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'tesis emlak vergisi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=94&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'depo kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2017-04-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=96&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'saha fesih sürecinin takibi', start: '2016-10-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=97&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'hafta tatil ruhsat harç ödemesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=98&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'saha ÇTV ödemesi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=99&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'saha kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2016-12-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=101&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: ' kira artış tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2017-01-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=102&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'emlak vergisi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=104&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Lastik değişim süreçleri ile ilgili olarak stok raporunun oluşturulması ve raporun dönem sonunda tutanak', start: '2016-10-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=105&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Lastik değişim süreçleri ilgili olarak stok raporunun olıuşturulması', start: '2016-10-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=106&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'merkez ÇTV ödeme', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=108&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'merkez emlak vergisi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=110&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'merkez hafta tatil ruhsat harç ödemesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=111&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'merkez ilan reklam vergisi  ödeme', start: '2016-10-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=112&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Merkez  bina ilan reklam vergi ödemesi', start: '2016-10-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=115&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Merkez bina ÇTV ödemesi', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=116&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Merkez bina emlak vergisi ödeme', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=122&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Merkez bina hafta tatili ruhsat harç ödemesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=124&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Merkez bina ilan reklam vergisi  ödeme', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=125&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Merkez bina ilan reklam vergisi beyanların verilmesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=126&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'emlak vergisi ödeme', start: '2016-11-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=129&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'hafta tatil ruhsat harç ödemesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=131&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'ilan reklam beyan verilmesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=132&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'ilan reklam vergis ödemesi', start: '2016-10-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=133&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'ilan reklam vergisi beyanın verilmesi vergi ödemesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=137&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2017-02-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=138&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yakıt Bilgilerinin Yöneticilere Gönderilmesi', start: '2016-10-05', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=139&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yakıt Kesintilerinin İK'ya Gönderilmesi', start: '2016-10-28', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=140&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'GSM Kesinti Bildirimleri (Personel)', start: '2016-10-10', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=141&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'İhale Süreci Şartname Hazırlanması', start: '2016-10-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=146&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2017-01-04', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=149&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2017-04-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=150&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2016-09-06', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=151&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yıllık fiyat artışı', start: '2016-10-03', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=152&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yurtdışı Arama Raporunun Hazırlanması', start: '2016-12-04', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=156&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Enflasyon ve yakıt oranında maliyetlerin güncellenmesi', start: '2016-10-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=158&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'ISG ve İlkyardım eğitimleri düzenlenmesi', start: '2017-02-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=159&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Kış lastiği uygulama tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2016-11-15', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=160&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Sağlık taraması', start: '2016-08-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=161&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Servis denetim formu', start: '2016-10-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=164&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Servis periyodik bakım tutanağı', start: '2016-09-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=166&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Şartnamenin Hazırlanması', start: '2017-06-15', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=167&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Yıllık maliyet değişim onayı', start: '2017-01-15', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=169&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Kışlık Kıyafet Verilmesi', start: '2016-09-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=172&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Özel güvenlik sigorta poliçesi', start: '2017-09-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=173&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Sirkülasyon tablosu', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=174&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Yazlık Kıyafet Verilmesi', start: '2017-04-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=177&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Tedarikçi değerlendirme toplantısı', start: '2016-10-02', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=178&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/01.png', title: 'Aylık Denetim', start: '2016-09-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=185&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Per. Servis aracı kamera kontrolü + kamera izleme (kural ihlali tespiti) raporun', start: '2016-09-25', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=187&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Servis değişim oranı tutanağı', start: '2016-10-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=188&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Shuttle Araç Kullanım Raporu', start: '2016-10-07', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=191&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Temz. Per. 6 Aylık Sirkülasyon Tutanağı', start: '2016-12-04', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=192&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/06.png', title: beyan verilmesi ve vergi ödemesi', start: '2017-01-31', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=194&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'GSM Kesinti Bildirimleri (IK)', start: '2016-10-28', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=196&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'Yasal Evrak Kontrolü ', start: '2016-10-01', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=197&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/07.png', title: 'araçlarınkullanım raporları çekilmesi ve maaş kesintisi onaylarının alınması', start: '2016-10-10', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=199&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Akaryakıt fiyat değişim tutanağının hazırlanması', start: '2016-09-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=200&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/04.png', title: 'Servis araçları ilaçlama ve hijyen tutanağı', start: '2016-09-30', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=201&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
                        { imageurl: 'http://localhost/contract/files/user_images/03.png', title: 'Aylık printer puantaj raporu kontrolü ', start: '2016-10-16', url: 'approve.php?busplan_ID=202&type=2', backgroundColor: '#0099CC' },
        ],
        eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
            eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl + "' width='30px' height='30px'/> ");
        }
    });

});
```

Thank you for your help. It will make me progress.

Comment: "working one page but another page isn't." does it mean when you switch to next day or month?

Comment: No. I mean I have two or more department. So, All departments have different events. For example, administration has .../?department_id=1 and purchase department has /?department_id=2.

Could be php memory insufficient?

Comment: It couldn't be a memory issue fullcalendar fetches limited events at a time. Also, I have run your code and is working fine. I have seen few of your dates in 2021. So could be the events you are trying to view is not appearing because of dates.

Comment: And if you have trouble viewing the image you can append the image in event title as well. 
Well, I see no issues in your code. Could be a date issue imo.

Comment: I searched dates added in database. Yes, It was date issue. I need to check dates before storing in database. Thank you Saurav

Comment: I think its worth mentioning for debugging purposes that if the calendar appears but no events is showing it can also be because the JSON data is not valid which can be checked here: [link](http://jsonlint.com). And if the JSON data is coming from a http request it can be viewed in chrome devtools (or similar tool for firefox) under the network tab.